# wami-recorder and Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I need my users to record a voice clip. I'm using [wami-recorder](https://code.google.com/p/wami-recorder/) to take care of the voice recording on the client side. I am using the default javascript functions:

```
Wami.startRecording('/upload?name=mysound.wav');
Wami.stopRecording();
```

In the chrome console, I can see the post request being sent successfully because, when I use the wami-recorder default url `"https://wami-recorder.appspot.com/audio"`, it works fine. But I can't seem to receive the file on the backend, Sinatra. How do I get the file and store it? Can someone point me in the right direction?

This is my controller:

```
post "/upload" do 
    p params
end
```

The output is just:

```
{"name"=>"file.wav"}
```

Answer (score 1):

The audio is posted as part of the raw body. I was able to save the file in rails using
  `request.raw_post`

on some brief googling it appears that you should be able to do the same in sinatra with
  `request.env["rack.input"].read`

You can then save this directly to a file

```
file = File.new("audio.wav", "w+b")
file.write request.env["rack.input"].read
file.close
```

This should save out a wav file within the same directory